# How can I repair my scratched dash?

Tags: damage, speedometer, dash

The car is a 3-year old Volvo V70. I just discovered I have two scratches right across the center of my dash, in a prime position to disturb/reflect the speedo needle. It's literally something I look at a hundred times every time I drive. Annoying!

I sometimes put my phone in front of the dash (because Google Maps is better than the built in navigation), and that's probably how I scratched it. Weird though, because the phone has a latex cover, but it's definitely something that feels a little rough against the back of my nail if I rub across the speedo "glass" (and, sadly, not something that will simply rub off).

Can I polish this piece of transparent plastic with something magical? Do I need the damn thing replaced entirely? That would surely cost a small fortune, based on all the doo-dads that would have to come off in order to reach it.

[image: speedo needle]
[image: two angles]

Comment: I had some abrasive goo in a tube back in the day made for getting scratches out of smartphones back when they had plastic faces instead of glass. It did work. I did it by hand, I didn't use a dremel or anything.

Answer (score 2):

My first suggestion would be to ask the Volvo dealership if the piece of perspex is available individually and at what price, you may find it is available.

Failing that, I'd say something like jewllers rouge on a cotton wheel would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

There are many remedies for polishing perspex/plexiglass. Some even mention using toothpaste. I think I would start with the finest possible polishing compound first and see if the scratch is disappearing. If it doesnt work, I would slowly go to more rough polishing compunds until I find the one which can level the scratched area, then go back to finer ones to shine/finish it. Things may get a little bit worse before getting better.

I think you can find may advices online about this. For example a simple web search about removing scratches from plexiglass returned few good ones:

http://www.plasweld.com.au/how-to-remove-scratches-from-acrylic-perspex/
http://www.howtocleanstuff.net/how-to-remove-scratches-from-plexiglass/
http://blog.theplasticpeople.co.uk/2012/01/27/how-to-remove-scratches-from-acrylic-perspex/